# How to get the output of an unnamed PL/SQL block in Oracle SQL Worksheet online? It's showing Unsupported Command for SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-output

I'm trying PL/SQL on online Oracle SQL Worksheet - [Live Oracle SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:3323436307214::NO:::).

I'm unable to display the output of the block, in spite of adding `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;`

This is my code

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

declare
    i number:=2;
    j number:=0;
    counter number:=0;
    flag number;
begin
    loop
        if (i=2) then
            counter:=counter+1;
            dbms_output.put(i ||' ');

        else
            j:=2;
            flag:=0;
            loop
                if(mod(i, j)=0) then
                    flag:=1;
                end if;
                exit when (i=j) or flag=1;
            end loop;
            if(flag=0) then
                counter:=counter+1;
                dbms_output.put(j ||' ');
            end if;
        end if;
    i:=i+1;
    exit when counter=10;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

This is the console message

```
Unsupported Command
Statement processed.
```

Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I actually changed `dbms_output.put()` to `dbms_output.put_line()` and it worked. Any idea how to make `dbms_output.put()` work?

I want the output in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

`DBMS_OUTPUT` will only output to the console when a full line of output has been produced. If you only use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` and don't call `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` or `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE` then the output will sit in a buffer somewhere but will never be written to the console.

From the [Oracle [`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT`] documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-1BCA24ED-0799-4ACA-9FB1-4CEC24FE41E7):

> Usage Notes:
>
> - When you call `PUT_LINE` the item you specify is automatically followed by an end-of-line marker. If you make calls to `PUT` to build a line, then you must add your own end-of-line marker by calling `NEW_LINE`. `GET_LINE` and `GET_LINES` do not return lines that have not been terminated with a newline character.

You want to add `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE` (or `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( NULL )`) at the end of your PL/SQL block.

A simplified version of your code (that only checks odd numbers) is:

```sql
DECLARE
  i       PLS_INTEGER :=1;
  j       PLS_INTEGER;
  counter PLS_INTEGER :=1;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('2 ');
  LOOP
    i:=i+2;
    j:=3;
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN mod(i, j)=0;
      j:= j + 2;
    END LOOP;
    IF i = j THEN
      -- prime found
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(i ||' ');
      counter:=counter+1;
      EXIT WHEN counter >= 10;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
> ```

Comment out that `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;` line and the procedure will not output anything as the buffer is never flushed to the console.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e678cb0cc29c4af4df2c9f50399dd4a)*